# Código JQuery não é executado

Tags: jquery

Estou seguindo um tutorial para fazer uma função AJAX que detecta a mudança em um `<select>` para carregar as informações em outro `<select>`. Fiz o mesmo que está no vídeo, mas o meu não está funcionando.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#aluno_naturalidade_uf').on('change', function(){
            alert('Funcionou!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Já coloquei um breakpoint na linha `$(document)`, mas ao clicar para passar a linha ele pula direto para `</script>`. As importações dos scripts deste template que estou usando estão o seguinte:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@2.2.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

O vídeo é este: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTfPlTCsVME 
O código fica pronto por volta dos 12:50min.

Edit: Após a pular para a linha `</script>` aparece essas informações no scope:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verificou algum erro no console?

Comment: No console não indica nenhum erro.

Comment: Consegue elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando na prática o comportamento?

Comment: É normal o debug ir para `</script>` direto, pois o seu código é assíncrono. A função que você definiu em `ready` será executada somente quando o DOM estiver carregado, não no momento que é analisado pelo navegador.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi. Mas esse ponto não está sendo executado quando eu mudo escolho outra opção no <select>

Comment: esse script está no fim como o video mostra? (antes de </body>)

Comment: @AnaTeixeira sim

Comment: Então elabore o [mcve] demonstrando esse comportamento. Com o snippet do site, botão `</>` do editor, você consegue fazer isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Como eu faço isso? Quero dizer, onde eu posso postar esse exemplo?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, acabei de detectar o erro. O id "aluno_naturalidade_uf" estava duplicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troca o `document ready` for `document on`.
Tenta isso:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#opcao", function()  {
  alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="opcao">
<option value="1">Primeira opção</option>
<option value="2">Segunda opção</option>
</select>
```